# How do I rearrange an array to be ordered with compatible neighbours?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, abstract

I have a rather abstract problem that I thought of but couldn’t figure out an efficient solution to it.

### Problem

Suppose we have a list of rules represented by an array of objects that all have an attribute that specifies an `Array[3]` of objects that it can be neighbors with:

```js
rules = [{
  id: 0,
  canMatchWith: [0, 1, 3, 5]
}, {
  id: 1,
  canMatchWith: [1, 0, 2, 12]
}, ...]
```

Each element can only be compatible with, let’s say 3 other elements, and itself.

### Questions

Given an array of `id`s as an input, not ordered and can have duplicates, what is an efficient algorithm that could output an array so that each element is present in its neighbors’ `canMatchWith` array?
Another interesting question is : can we quickly determine if the given input has at least one solution before trying?
Also: is this a sorting problem? And would it be better to use graphs and nodes rather than arrays?

All my attempts involve going through the input array multiple times while ordering a single item and if it’s a dead end, it just starts over, which is not good enough.

I don’t necessarily need a full solution, pointers and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret this as a graph traversal problem:

- Your values are the nodes of a graph
- The "compatible" relation are the edges (ie, there is an edge between two nodes of the graph, if they can be ordered next to each other)

Then your sorting algorithm is a graph traversal problem, where you search for a path through the graph, passing each node exactly once. I didn't search for a specific algorithm, but I bet there are some algorithms out there, can determine whether such an order (ie graph traversal) is possible at all, and if yes, how it looks like ...